# Which character attribute affects staff bolt attack?

Tags: darkfall-unholy-wars

In Darkfall: Unholy Wars, a character has base attributes (str / dex / int / wis). Each serve a clear purpose as it relates to "primary role stat" and how it affects an attack.

Now melee and ranged apply seemingly to, melee weapons and missile weapons (bows / thrown)

But what is not clear is what stat affects the "Staff Bolt" function of staffs. Which of the attributes affect this attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that currently, only intelligence (INT) affects (as in scales up the effectiveness of) the "Staff Bolt" attack.

**EDIT**:

It's stated here in [this guide](http://www.postcount.net/forum/showthread.php?36522-Darkfall-Guide) as well as in [these tutorial videos](https://forums.darkfallonline.com/showthread.php?362900-Uzik-s-Ultimate-DFUW-Guide).

Comment: if you can find a reputable source that substantiates this, then I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I know there's [this guide](http://www.postcount.net/forum/showthread.php?36522-Darkfall-Guide) but, it's a bit old (from beta about 4-5 months back). It is also mentioned in [these tutorial videos](https://forums.darkfallonline.com/showthread.php?362900-Uzik-s-Ultimate-DFUW-Guide)

Comment: My concern with this resource is this line : `Intelligence is increased by casting spells or staff bolt` - which is not true for Darkfall:Unholy wars. It IS accurate for Darkfall (the original game). In "Unholy Wars" stats, skills etc... are raised via "prowess" points. The exception for this is crafting is raised by doing. This was a change in how stats and weapon / spell skills are raised